# Equity share on first home

Tags: first-time-home-buyer, home

My girlfriend and I are buying our first home together. As it stands, I'll be putting quite a large chunk of the deposit (roughly 70%) and I'll be paying about 60% of the monthly mortgage repayments.

Is there a convenient tool / method for calculating the equity split we get? I know it's not going to be 50/50 because of my larger contribution; I just want some way of getting a good idea.

from the comments: Yes, so we understand that there needs to be a written agreement drafted by a Lawyer. That much is obvious to us. I just want to get a feeling for how to calculate what the split will be in the agreement.

Comment: Just my 2 cents worth of personal advice: co-owning a home without sharing money more generally sounds like a Bad Idea to me. Sharing paychecks and bank accounts is much more reversible than sharing a house, and is a lower level of financial commitment. Have you considered having just one of you own the house, while the other pays some reasonable "rent" to help out with the payments?

Comment: What happens if she gets pregnant in few years, and takes off 3-6 months or more? She's likely to paid significantly less those months. Will you re-do the equity split? What if you end up out of work for a year? Modify the equity? If you're serious enough to buy a house together, split it 50-50, and don't worry about it. Or write a contract that the down payment amounts will be recovered from any profit on sale first, then split the rest 50-50.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the equity doesn't have to be directly proportional to the amounts each of you has contributed -- and depending on where you are and your particular situation that may not be the law's default. If you are at all concerned about the ownership -- and you should be -- ***sit down with a lawyer and put your agreement in writing.*** Otherwise what you assume is happening may not be what is actually happening... And having something like this to argue about makes both relationships and separation much more painful.

However, if that is the formula you want to use, it's straightforward: Track the totals of how much each of you has contributed to the purchase (and upkeep? You need to think about that) of the house. The ratio of your equity, under this system , is the same as the ratio between your contributions. One can work out a formula for that, but it's just as easy to work with the real numbers.

Comment: Okay yep, So that was exactly my thinking too. But I just wanted to make sure that there was no hidden stuff to come along and catch us out. My girlfriend and I are pretty set on keeping things a fair as possible, so in the unlikely event of a break up, there's no debate about who owns what. We get what we bought type thing. This answers my question, so happy to mark as an answer. Thanks Keshlam.

Comment: This is a contract. The division of equity is what the two of you agree it is. If you want to make it 50/50 despite the difference in contributions, it if you want to scale the contributions by what percentage if each person's income they represent, or anything else, that's up to you. Decide what you both consider equitable, and put it in writing.

Comment: Yep, I understand that and I think the point we've agreed to thus far is that the division of equity will be proportional to our individual contributions to both the deposit and the monthly mortgage repayments, so that should make calculations pretty straight forward.

Comment: I'd look at the difference of 70 on deposit and 60 on ongoing expenses. If the numbers were equal this would feel a bit simpler.

Comment: Hi Joe, they were rough estimates. I'd like to be spot on exact with her. I feel quite strongly about this being as fair as possible. I know it's poor form to ask a second question in the comments, but do you think that going purely off monetary contribution without consideration of our respective incomes is the fairest way to do it?

Comment: @christopher There is nothing fair or unfair. Its how both of you see it. One can purely go by contributions. It makes things simpler. One can also go by income. One can also bring in non tangibles. i.e. You can think, your girlfriend is getting to enjoy a bigger house by paying less. Your girlfriend can think she is supporting your dream of bigger house.

Comment: Exactly. What is fair is what you two consider fair.

Comment: @christopher - the whole scenario boils down to 2 issues. Putting the split details in writing. And having that split feel fair to both of you. There are issues when a couple have different incomes, or very different spending. That turns into a psychology question. I was fortunate to have a wife who averaged about 10% more income than me over the 30 years we worked together. I didn't judge her shoe or pocketbook purchases, she didn't judge my electronics. But we saved together right off the top.